# How to validate request.POST.get() is not None and not empty is there any easy way to handle?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to validate my ***`request.POST`*** data if it is **null** or **empty** I'm redirecting to error page I've tried this way if there is better way to handle this please let me know.

```
    given_name = request.POST.get('given_name')
    surname = request.POST.get('surname')
    gender = request.POST.get('gender')
    DOB = request.POST.get('DOB')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    address = request.POST.get('address')

    if given_name == "" or given_name == None or surname == "" or surname == None or gender == "" or gender == None or DOB == "" or DOB == None or email == "" or email == None or phone == "" or phone == None or address == "" or address == None:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the truthiness of both the empty string and `None` are `False`, so you can check with:

```
if not given_name or not surname or … or not address:
    # …
```

But you better make use of a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/). Django's forms can both validate and clean data and remove a lot of boilerplate code. You can define for example a `Form`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    given_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    gender = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    DOB = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128, required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
```

then you can construct a form and validate:

```
myform = MyForm(request.POST)
if myform.is_valid():
    # …
```

the `email` field will not only validate that it is not an empty string, but also that this is indeed an email address. It thus make sophisticated validations more convenient.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much  @Willem Van Onsem.